# Verilog : How to assign values to 2 random indexes in a big array?

Tags: arrays, verilog

I have an array made like

```
genvar p;
    generate
        for (p = 0 ; p < 128 ; p = p + 1)
            begin
                assign fft_bin_th1[p] = (array_x[p] > threshold_1)? 1'b1 : 1'b0;

            end
    endgenerate
```

The array fft_bin_th1 contain 4 ones at random locations after this statement. After doing some operations I get 2 values of indexes , lets say 23 and 42 (they are random). These were 1s in fft_bin_th1 array. 
     I want to assign these 2 indexes (23 and 42) the value zero and rest of array fft_bin_th1 should be same. How can I do this?

Comment: Instead of `assign`, you can have combinational `always` block to add additional logic for driving `fft_bin...`.

Answer (score 1):

From what I can understand you are looking for a code like

```
always@(posedge clk) 
begin
  index_1 <= logic_to_get_index1;
  index_2 <= logic_to_get_index2;  
  fft_bin_th1[index_1] <= 0;
  fft_bin_th1[index_2] <= 0;
end
```

`